# DetailViewController always show the same content view when i click the different row in UITableView

Tags: ios5, uitableview

The parent tableViewController contains ten row in correspondence to different UIImageView for the detailViewController. When i clicked UItableViewCell by random, It can be push correct UIImageView for detailViewController, But if i clicked backButton on NavigationBar to return to parent tableviewController. Whatever which cell was clicked in UITableView,But it's always show the same UIImageView for DetailViewController which i just selected before. Is there any solution? Very appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the prepareForSegue method in your initial viewController.. and you also have to set a property for a variable in your DetailViewController that will be filled by the initial viewController in the prepareForSegue Method.

After that, in your detailViewController viewDidLoad method, depending on the variable set by the prepareForSegue from the initial viewController, you will show different images.. keeo in mind that will also need a IBOutlet or this ImageView in your detailView storyboard..

Comment: thank you for your reply. But i use didSelectRowatIndexPahth method to fulfill that,not using storyboard.

Comment: itworks the same way... in didSelectRow you set a var in the detail viewcontroller to correspond to the selected row.. and in the detailviewcontroller viewdidload you read this var and decide what image to show